# Installing Python on iSH

Tags: python

Not long ago my computer broke and I am stuck on an iPad. I installed iSH from the AppStore. Now I want to download Python and **make sure `pip` works**.

I have tried apk add python, which lead to the pip issue, but pip installing is important for me. I have also found other ways using yam or apt(-get), but I do not know how to download either of them.

Comment: did you try `apk --update-cache add python3 python3-dev py3-pip`?

Comment: Pip is a little slow, but works.

Comment: what is architecture of Linux? (`uname -a`) is it `x86`? If yes, that is explain why `pip` is slow. Because of `ARM` → `x86` emulation

Comment: zhouhualideiPad:~# uname -a
Linux zhouhualideiPad 4.20.69-ish iSH 1.2.3 (298) Dec 17 2021 06:08:24 i686 Linux @rzlvmp what does that mean?

Comment: `what does that mean?` → 1. `iSH` emulating Linux environment with kernel version `4.20` that is already [outdated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel_version_history#Releases_4.x.y) (not a big deal if you don't plan to develop Linux drivers :) ). 2. `iSH` emulating `x86` (= `i686`)  CPU architecture. That is not `ARM` native so heavy applications may be slow. Also you can't run or build modern `x64` application on `iSH`. [Article](https://nomadic-dmitry.medium.com/apple-silicon-m1-how-to-run-x86-and-arm-virtual-machines-on-it-cdd9d9054483) about emulation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According information that you provided `iSH` using virtual environment with Alpine Linux x86 under the hood (I little bit simplify explanation, so it is not 100% correct. You can see details [here](https://jsmp.me/2020/05/05/c-development-on-ios)).

So if you want to install `pip` you have to search [how to install pip in Alpine Linux](https://www.google.com/search?q=alpine%20linux%20install%20pip). You will find many answers like [that](https://ittutorialpoint.com/how-to-install-python-in-alpine-linux/):

```bash
apk add --update-cache python3 py3-pip
```

This information applicable to any other package that you will try to install. Not just pip.

Comment: Doesn’t work anymore.